# Card wont scroll all the way to the top

Tags: html, css, flask, scrollbar, card

All my webpages use a card that changes size using '%'. But that makes it so that it wont scroll to the top. When I use a specified size like 300px then it would scroll all the way but I also want my site to be mobile-friendly so I need it to change based on the browser size. If this helps im using flask and my html that uses this just uses `<div class='card'> content </div>`. This is my card:

```
.card {
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background: #22222a;
  border: 2px solid white;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  max-height: 100%
}
```

And my body if that does anything with the size:

```
body {
  font-family: Rubik, sans-serif;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  background:
    linear-gradient(
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75), 
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75)
    ),
    url(static.gif);
  }
}
```

Heres what it looks like on a small display:
[Card showing scrollbar at top although content isn't there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yRoaD.png)

And if you want to test it yourself [heres the webpage shown in the image](https://coolkase.dev/tpt)

I looked this up and didn't find anything about this problem so I haven't tried anything yet.